# Было: и... (то), и... (сё), затем: "А потом и конечно же домашняя курица", - ничего?

Tags: пунктуация

> Ну а потом и мясо с огня поспело. А потом **и конечно же** домашняя
>   курица (здесь считается, что резать надо молодого петушка), и домашние
>   же свиные рёбрышки.

Answer (score 1):

*А потом и, **конечно же**, домашняя курица...*

**Здесь** надо бы вводное слово обособить, сравнить: А потом и домашняя курица, конечно же.

Обособляют ***конечно же*** часто, и Грамота советует:
[http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=И%2C+конечно+же](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%98%2C+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B6%D0%B5)

Обычно нет обособления ***и конечно же***  в начале предложения, хотя  всякое бывает (иногда происходит переход в наречие), так что от структуры  много зависит.

Примеры:

**И конечно же,** весь мир надеялся на трудолюбивый Китай.

**И конечно же** присутствует доверие, иначе быть не может.

И ты **конечно же** с ходу ей отвечаешь…

В школе в первую очередь смотрят на языковую подготовку и, **конечно же**, на умение ладить с детьми.